# Postgres remove constraint by column names

Tags: postgresql, post

Is there a way I can remove a constraint based on column names?

I have postgres 8.4 and when I upgrade my project the upgrade fails because a constraint was named something different in a different version.

Basically, I need to remove a constraint if it exists or I can just remove the constraint using the column names.

The name of the constraint is the only thing that has changed. Any idea if that's possible?

In this case, I need to remove "patron_username_key"

```
discovery=# \d patron
                       Table "public.patron"
          Column          |            Type             | Modifiers
--------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 patron_id                | integer                     | not null
 create_date              | timestamp without time zone | not null
 row_version              | integer                     | not null
 display_name             | character varying(255)      | not null
 username                 | character varying(255)      | not null
 authentication_server_id | integer                     |
Indexes:
    "patron_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (patron_id)
    "patron_username_key" UNIQUE, btree (username, authentication_server_id)
```

Comment: What kind of constraint? Foreign key? Check constraint? Not Null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that unique index is the result of adding a unique constraint, you can use the following SQL statement to remove that constraint:

```
do $$
declare 
  cons_name text;
begin
  select constraint_name 
     into cons_name
  from information_schema.constraint_column_usage  
  where constraint_schema = current_schema()
  and column_name in ('authentication_server_id', 'username')
  and table_name = 'patron'
  group by constraint_name
  having count(*) = 2;

  execute 'alter table patron drop constraint '||cons_name;
end;
$$
```

I'm not sure if this will work if you have "only" added a unique index (instead of a unique constraint).

If you need to do that for more than 2 columns you also need to adjust the `having count(*) = 2` part to match the number of columns in the `column_name in ..` condition.

(As you did not specify your PostgreSQL version I'm assuming the current version)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System Catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalogs.html) to find information bout constraints. Still, some constraints, like keys, are mentioned in the separate `pg_constraint` table, while others, like `NOT NULL`, are essentially a columns in the `pg_attribute` table.

For the keys, you can use this query to get a list of constraint definitions:

```
SELECT pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) AS def
  FROM pg_class t
  JOIN pg_constraint c ON c.conrelid=t.oid
 WHERE t.relkind='r' AND t.relname = 'table';
```

You can then filter out the ones that references your column and dynamically construct `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT ...` statements.